# dbt snapshot fails on schema change in nested column

Tags: dbt

I get snapshop datatypes error

> Value has type STRUCT<module STRING, reference_entity_class STRING,
> reference_table STRING, ...> which cannot be inserted into column
> created_by, which has type STRUCT<module STRING,
> reference_entity_class STRING, reference_table STRING, ...> at [16:33]

the problematic column is a struct and there were new fields/subcolumns added. Does this mean snapshots cannot account for schema changes in nested columns, or am i missing something?
Thank you so much in advance!
Attached on the left is the updated schema of the tmp table to be merged, on the right is the original table
[image]

Comment: You probably have to `alter` the column manually. You should open this as an issue in the `dbt-bigquery` repo!

Comment: @tconbeer thanks for reply, i was hoping there another way other than manually altering the column. Will open an issue then